# Display modal popup div overtop of full-screen video

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, html5-video, fullscreen

We have a website that displays a video using the html5 video tag. The video is typically displayed in line, but the user has the option of using full screen. At various times, we need to display a popup that disappears after the user clicks ok or a period of time has elapsed. We have this working with inline video and in full screen by exiting full screen while the modal is displayed then going back to full screen when it goes away.

However, the client wants the modal to display without exiting full screen at all. This is supposed to work on multiple non-IE browsers on Windows, Macs, iPhones, iPads, and Android devices. Is this even possible? If so, what's the best way to do this? My Google-fu has failed me so far...

If it matters, we need this on 2 different sites: one using Angular and one using .NET Core Razor with Bootstrap.